# Environment variable TEXEDIT doesn't work with LuaLaTeX (?)

Tags: luatex, environment-variables

I like the ability to press <kbd>e</kbd> when running `pdflatex` in `errorstopmode` to jump directly to the line where the error occurs in my favourite editor.

This works fine for `pdflatex` and `xelatex` as long as the variable `TEXEDIT` (which seems to be responsible of this behaviour) is set to the right editor.

I've set (my editor is WinEdt)

```
TEXEDIT=WinEdt.exe "[Open(|%s|);SelPar(%d,7);]"
```

in a PC with TeX Live 2013 installed.

Anyway, I can't get it working with `lualatex`. I mean, when I have an error in the line 21 in a file called `test.tex`, the console output of `lualatex` is:

```
You want to edit file ./test.tex at line 21
```

but it doesn't jump at all to the line with the error.

So, the question is: do I have to set a different environment variable for `lualatex` or is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same here (TeX Live 2013, Win 7): pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX open an editor (I used Notepad as this is always available on Windows), but LuaLaTeX just gives the message. I see the same odd behaviour with a MiKTeX install (which opens TeXworks as standard for pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX but fails to for LuaLaTeX). I also see the problem on my Mac TeX Live 2013 set up.

I raised this on the LuaTeX list, and Taco Hoekwater (LuaTeX developer) said

> That is deliberate.

So I guess you just have to accept this is 'by design'.

Comment: So it is a bug... I spent hours for finding a solution... Thanks.

Comment: I submitted a bug ticket a few years ago (2011-06-01...) http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=670. But Taco didn't do anything about it yet.